# Continuous function on R which tends to infinity on open interval must have a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose we have $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $$\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \infty.$$

Then must $f$ have a minimum on $\mathbb{R}$?  Intuitively it seems so, and it's easy to prove for some arbitrary closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Extreme Value Theorem, but how can we apply that to an open interval like $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: you mean the limit is $+ \infty$? Otherwise $x^3$ is a counterexample

Comment: $\infty$ means $+\infty$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a number $M$ with the property that $|x| > M$ implies $f(x) > f(0)$. This follows from the definition of the limit at $\pm \infty$.

$f$ attains a minimum on the interval $[-M,M]$.

If this minimum occurs at $x_0$ you have $f(x_0) \le f(x)$ for all $|x| \le M$ and $f(x_0) \le f(0) \le f(x)$ for all $|x| > M$. Thus $f$ has a global minimum at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}f(x)=\infty$ we have that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$ there exist $y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $|f(x)|>M$ for all $x\in (-\infty,-y)\cup (z,+\infty)$. Restrict $f$ to $[y,z]$ and use the fact that on compact subsets continuous functions attain a minimum.

You still need to make this argument precise, do you see why this argument is not 100% ok?

Edit, I'm always to late with my answers...